# CUDA vs. CuBlas memory management

Tags: memory, cuda, cublas

I have noticed that I can use memory blocks for matrices either allocated using cudamalloc() or cublasalloc() function to call cublas functions. The matrix transfer rates and computational are slower for arrays allocated using cudamalloc() rather than cublasalloc(), although there are other advantages to using arrays using cudamalloc(). Why is that the case? It would be great to hear some comments.

Comment: Do you see this when working with floats, doubles, or both?  It could be an alignment issue (`cudaAlloc()` takes an `elemSize` argument, but `cudaMalloc()` doesn't).

Comment: I was working with floats in both cases. Haven't seen this in double as I don't need to work with doubles in my application. I'll check with cudaAlloc at the same time.

Comment: Btw, Gabriel, do you mean ''cublasAlloc()'' rather than ''cudaAlloc()''?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.  If you're seeing this with floats, then I don't know what to say about the performance difference.

Comment: If you're just looking to optimize, check out the 2D aligned `pitch` mallocs for cublas (you'll need to use the `lda` and `ldb` terms in BLAS appropriately).  It may give a significant speedup.  And of course there's pinned memory too.

Comment: I've looked at pinned memory. It looks promising as I can allocate memory on the host that is accessible by the GPU (especially when the memory on my GPU is on the low end). I saw some example code posted http://www.ddj.com/architect/217500110 . However, would there be any significant performance downsides b/c of additional memory access transfers that goes on between operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cublasAlloc` is essentially a wrapper around `cudaMalloc()` so there should be no difference, is there anything else that changes in your code?